# DATE_ADD function doesn't work in Update

Tags: mysql, sql-update, dateadd

I'm trying the following SQL:

```
update Sales_details set due_date = DATE_ADD(last_sale_date, INTERVAL 35 DAY) where task = 230
```

and got following error

> syntax error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'INTERVAL35DAY) FROM Sales_details WHERE task =
>   230' at line 1

I've tried the following SQL and it's working fine:

```
select last_sale_date, DATE_ADD(last_sale_date, INTERVAL 35 DAY) from Sales_details where task = 230
```

Why the `DATE_ADD` doesn't work in `Update` Statement?

Answer (score 0):

Works for mysql!! Your syntax is wrong- you are using the syntax of mysql in sqlserver,

Please check syntax of ADDDATE for SQLSERVER

```
SQL Server DATEADD() Function
DATEADD(datepart,number,date)


MySQL DATE_ADD() Function
DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr type)


mysql> select first_name,birth_date from students where first_name = 'Dale';
+------------+------------+
| first_name | birth_date |
+------------+------------+
| Dale       | 1959-03-29 |
+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update students set birth_date = DATE_ADD(birth_date,interval 35 DAY) where first_name = 'Dale';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select first_name,birth_date from students where first_name = 'Dale';    +------------+------------+
| first_name | birth_date |
+------------+------------+
| Dale       | 1959-05-03 |
+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: This is MySql Server:Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: Percona Server
Server version: 5.5.42-37.1 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 37.1, Revision 727
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Why is DATE_ADD working in SELECT Statement but doesn't in UPDATE?